# order of execution in Salesforce isuue

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, before-trigger, triggercontext

i need a small clarification on the order of execution in salesforce.
Like i have trigger and Workflow field update both on Record **insert** operation/event, so in this case the final value will be from Workflow ,which is working fine.

But in case of Record **update** operation/event, its taking the final value from trigger(and not from WF field update).

As per the documentation ,Workflow fires after the trigger, then why in the Update scenario above ,final value is coming from Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A Workflow Field Update triggers a second round of before and after triggers, so if a workflow and trigger both operate on the same field, the trigger will win. As explained in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> 11. Executes workflow rules. If there are workflow field updates:
>
> a. Updates the record again.
>
> b. Runs system validations again. Custom validation rules, flows, duplicate rules, processes, and escalation rules aren’t run again.
>
> c. Executes before update triggers and after update triggers, regardless of the record operation (insert or update), one more time (and only one more time)

Note 11(c) is applicable here. Your update triggers will run if a Workflow Field Update results in a modification to a record.

For this reason, it is important that you choose one or the other method of updating records. You should not mix declarative features (Workflow Rules, Flows) with code (triggers) on the same object.

Comment: ..point is incase of insert Workflow is winning..that is my confusion...in that case trigger is not updating

Comment: the above thing which u told works very correctly in UPDATE operation...that's y the confusion

Comment: @SFDCLWC You'd have to check the debug logs. In case of insert, you have an insert trigger > workflow field update > update trigger. In an update, you have an update trigger > workflow field update > update trigger. Also, note that if the record isn't actually modified by the field update, the triggers won't fire again., even if the workflow rule is triggered.

Comment: yes u re right...in the logs ...it is the same order the way you told and its workflow field update action only...if u try u also will get the same result...that's y i have posted it over here....dont know what exactly is the issue?

Comment: like WF whenever it is created ,it is updating industry to Banking, and Before insert trigger updates it to Finance...the final value upon record insertion is Banking.

Comment: infact if the trigger is before update also, then also WF is winning... when i change the evaluation criteria to Created and Everytime its edited and UPDATING the record...then trigger is winning.